# Open and display excel spreadsheet in HTML window and manipulate data

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement is to create a webpage where after clicking on a button/hyperlink, a window will open in same page, and that window should show excel spreadsheet.

Please note that I know how to open an excel in HTML window but here i want to **display excel spreadsheet in editable format in my webpage developed in HTML window.**

Please let me know if this is achievable through HTML, Javascripting.

Thanks.

Comment: So how *do* you open an Excel file in an HTML window?

Comment: Are you interested in displaying the data(which would be editable) in a tabular format like excel, or you want to use excel mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Yes Prateek. I want to display the data which shud be editable. Basically it shud open excel itself in HTML window in editable format.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've asked only to read the data you can simply export the spreadsheet to html and from there it'll work like any other webpage. Here are the instructions: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/674-excel-export-to-html.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Javascript library to display data as excel in html](http://www.activewidgets.com/) you can pass your data in different formats as well, ex:- json, list, array etc.

Comment: Thanks Prateek. I saw the utility and it contains VB, .NET code. Can it not be done with only plain HTML and Javascript embedded in HTML code?